# Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘dynfactoR’

Tags: r

```
icc_hp_filtro <- hpfilter(icc, freq = 12, type = "frequency")
icc_brecha <- ((icc - icc_hp_filtro$trend)/icc_hp_filtro$trend) * 100

#Análisis factorial dinámico para reducir la cantidad de variables explicativas en preparación para ARDL

series_tiempo_diff <- cbind(icc, icc_brecha)

plot(series_tiempo_diff, main = "Gráfico de los datos en diferencia logarítmica y factor dinámico", 
     xlab = "Año y mes")

fact_din <- dynfactoR::dfm(as.matrix(series_tiempo_diff)[2:83])
```

> **Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘dynfactoR’**

Comment: I dont know how to resolve this errror!!!

Comment: [devtools::install_github("rbagd/dynfactoR")](https://github.com/rbagd/dynfactoR)